# How to remove references to remote branches from my local git repository

Tags: git

When I type `git branch` in my local repository, I get this:

```
* master
  minor/branch_1
  origin&minor/branch_2
  origin/minor/branch_2
```

How can I remove the last two references from my local repository without affecting the remote one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git branch` without options should only show local branches and shouldn't include remote-tracking branches. Are you sure those are not local branches with awkward names? If so, delete them like any other local branch:

```
git branch -d 'origin&minor/branch_2' 'origin/minor/branch_2'
```

If they are unmerged branches, use `-D`. Note that this will make the commits of the branches unreachable and they will eventually be fully deleted from your Git repository